# Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option

Tags: android, kotlin

I updated kotlin version on Android studio

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

Unfortunately I am getting build error

> Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just set in your module build.gradle file:

```
   android {
   // ...
      kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs += [
            '-Xjvm-default=enable'
        ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: Simple and sweet!!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the answer. Can you expand the answer to explain why this is needed?

Answer (score 0):

`default` is now deprecated and `default=all|all-compatibility` should be used instead.

```
w: '-Xjvm-default=enable' is deprecated, please use '-Xjvm-default=all|all-compatibility'
```